# How to make a dictionary entry from each line in a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary

So, i have this text file which contains this infos:

```
student_num1 student_name1 student_grade1
student_num2 student_name2 student_grade2
student_num3 student_name3 student_grade3
```

What i want to do is i want to take each line of this text file as a dictionary entry with this format:

```
students = { student_num1: [student_name1, student_grade1], student_num2: [student_name2, student_grade2], student_num3: [student_name3, student_grade3] }
```

Basically, the first string of the line should be  the key and the 2 strings next to it would be the value. But i don't know how will i make python separate the strings in each line and assign them as the key and value for the dictionary.

EDIT:
So, i've tried some code: (I saw all your solutions, and i think they'll all definitely work, but i also want to learn to create my solution, so i will really appreciate if you could check mine!)

```
for line in fh:
    line = line.split(";")
    student_num = line[0]
    student_name = line[1]
    student_grade = line[2]

    count =+ 1
    direc[student_num] = [student_name,student_grade]
    student_num = "student_num" + str(count)
    student_grade = "student_grade" + str(count)
    student_name = "student_name" + str(count)

print(direc)
```

The problem is i get an error of list index out of range on line 10 or this part "student_name = line[1]"

EDIT: THANK YOU EVERYONE! Every single one of your suggested solutions works! I've also fixed my own solution. This is the fixed one (as suggest by @norok2):

```
for line in fh:
    line = line.split(" ")
    student_num = line[0]
    student_name = line[1]
    student_grade = line[2]

    count =+ 1
    direc[student_num] = [student_name,student_grade]
    student_num = "student_num" + str(count)
    student_grade = "student_grade" + str(count)
    student_name = "student_name" + str(count)
```

Comment: What have you searched for and what did you find? Based on that, what did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: @tripleee I've been searching for a while now and i can't seem to find a solution. My idea was that i wanted to try to make each line as a list and then use that list as entries for my dictionary, but the problem is 1: i don't know the proper syntax to separate each line and make each one a list and 2: i also have no idea how to make python recognize each element in the list as key and the value

Comment: So you can [edit] the question to show how you `open` the file and iterate over the lines, and mark the place where you are stuck. Hint: `split()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current approach uses file handling to open a file in read mode, and then reading the lines present in the file. Then for each line, remove extra new line and whitespaces and split it at space, to create a list. Then used unpacking to store single value as `key` and a list of 2 values as `value`. Added values to the dictonary.

**temp.txt**

```
student_num1 student_name1 student_grade1
student_num2 student_name2 student_grade2
student_num3 student_name3 student_grade3
```

**main.py**

```
d = dict()
with open("temp.txt", "r") as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    key, *values = line.strip().split(" ")
    d[key] = values
  print(d)
```

**Output**

```
{'student_num1': ['student_name1', 'student_grade1'], 'student_num2': ['student_name2', 'student_grade2'], 'student_num3': ['student_name3', 'student_grade3']}
```

Answer (score 3):

As a dict comprehension:

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    students = {k:v for k, *v in map(str.split, f)}
```

Explanation:

The file object `f` is already an iterator (that yields each line), we want to split the lines, so we can use `map(str.split, f)` or `(line.split() for line in f)`.
After that we know, that the first item is the key of the dictionary, and the remaining items are the values. We can use unpacking for that. An unpacking example:

```
>>> a, *b = [1,2,3]
>>> a
1
>>> b
[2, 3]
```

Then we use a comprehension to build the dict with the values we are capturing in the unpacking. 
A dict comprehension is an expresion to build up dictionaries, for example:

```
>>> {x:x+1 for x in range(5)}
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}
```

Example,

File data.txt:

```
student_num1 student_name1 student_grade1 
student_num2  student_name2 student_grade2 
student_num3 student_name3 student_grade3
```

Reading it

```
>>> with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
...     students = {k:v for k, *v in map(str.split, f)}
... 
>>> students
{'student_num1': ['student_name1', 'student_grade1'], 'student_num2': ['student_name2', 'student_grade2'], 'student_num3': ['student_name3', 'student_grade3']}
```

Comment: It works,  thank you! But could you explain  what  the  code does after  the with open... part?

Comment: @Gatts, sure, check the explanation and feel free to ask!

Comment: i get it now! Thank you so much for the help :))

Answer (score 1):

```py
with open('data.txt') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
d = {}
for line in lines:
  tokens = line.split()
  d[tokens[0]] = tokens[1:]
print(d)
```

I hope this is understandable. To split the lines into the different tokens, we use the split[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function.

Comment: Hello! Could you check my own solution? I've edited my post. Edit: I've also tried your code and it works! Thank you!

Comment: @Gatts I see that you are using line.split(";"). This will split the string based on the character ';'. However, I see that you are working with spaces between the student number, grade, and number, so you should either call split with no parameter or with a space (' ') as the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your solution is giving you that error is that it seems your lines do not contain the character `;`, yet you try to split by that character with `line = line.split(";")`.

You should replace that with:

- `line = line.split(" ")` to split by the space character

or

- `line = line.split(";")` to split by any blank character

---

However, for a more elegant solution, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58200297/5218354).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something as simple as this:

```
d = {}
with open('students.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, *rest = line.split()
        d[key] = rest

print(d)
# {'student_num1': ['student_name1', 'student_grade1'], 'student_num2': ['student_name2', 'student_grade2'], 'student_num3': ['student_name3', 'student_grade3']}
```

Answer (score 0):

**file.txt:**

```
student_num1 student_name1 student_grade1
student_num2 student_name2 student_grade2
student_num3 student_name3 student_grade3
```

**Main.py:**

```
def main():
    file = open('file.txt', 'r')
    students = {}
    for line in file:
        fields = line.split(" ")
        fields[2] = fields[2].replace("\n", "")
        students[fields[1]] = [fields[0], fields[2]]

    print(students)
main()
```

**Output:**

```
{'student_name1': ['student_num1', 'student_grade1'], 'student_name2': ['student_num2', 'student_grade2'], 'student_name3': ['student_num3', 'student_grade3']}
```